# Disabling Contextual Action Bar Crosswalk-Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, contextual-action-bar, crosswalk

Contextual Action Bar (CAB) **won't disable** using Crosswalk as a plugin in Cordova.

Tried everything, starting with the CSS, all the way through HTML & JavaScript, and even MainActivity.java & XWalkCordovaView.java.

**I must disable the Contextual Action Bar**. It cannot show up. It's messing my entire app. It needs to be gone, completely. Or at least, I settle with not seeing it in my app.
Here are some pictures:
[image]
As you see, **we need to select text and show that toolbar** (the black one, and disable the blue contextbar, prevent it from showing at all). It's not allowing us to use our toolbar. I mean, with Contextual Action Bar, NO WYSIWYG will work nicely.

I even have problems with the arrow select, which I'd like to disable as well, or at least change the color, or not mess up the sidenav.
[image]

So, what I tried:
MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
loadUrl(launchUrl);
// disable the context menu and all long clicks
super.appView.getView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{ return true; }
});
super.appView.getView().setLongClickable(false);
}
}
```

From here:
[How to disable long-click which opens the Android top menu bar with copy/paste/etc. buttons in Cordova Crosswalk apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949401/how-to-disable-long-click-which-opens-the-android-top-menu-bar-with-copy-paste-e)
Pull Request: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/pull/3193
Now, please, I need to disable the Contextual Action Bar when I select some text. Thank you so much in advance. I've searched the whole web and nothing seems to work.

I've filled an issue on Crosswalk Project's Issues:

https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7206